# Separar cadena en partes mediante una condición de longitud JAVA

Tags: java, string, spring, split

Tengo un problema Recibo una cadena dinámica de casi siempre con más de 10.000 caracteres, lo que necesito es separar esa cadena en n números de partes, cada parte debe tener como maximo 3.999 caracteres y esas cadenas agregarlas a una lista.
Mi problema es que he investigado las propiedades split, substring y no he encontrado nada que separe una cadena mediante una longitud definida.
Ejemplo:

```
//cada palabra tendria 3.999 caracteres
String cadena = "primercadenas egundacadena terceracadena cuartacadena";
```

alguna función o propiedad que me permita separar toda la cadena en partes de 3.999 caracteres

Answer (score 1):

Puedes separarlo valiéndote de una expresión regular, por ejemplo, con esta divido la cadena en elementos de 5 caracteres de longitud:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
    "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890".split("(?<=\\G.{5})")
));
```

Que produce la salida:

```
[12345, 67890, 12345, 67890, 12345, 67890, 12345, 67890, 12345, 67890]
```

### Explicación

`\G` es una aserción de tamaño cero que coincide con la posición donde terminó la coincidencia anterior. Si *no hubo* coincidencia anterior, coincide con el comienzo de la entrada, lo mismo que `\A`. La búsqueda hacia atrás adjunta coincide con la posición que está a N caracteres desde el final de la última coincidencia, 5 en el ejemplo.

Tanto lookbehind como `\G` son características avanzadas de las expresiones regulares, que no son compatibles con todos los sabores. Además, `\G` no se implementa de manera consistente en todos los sabores que lo admiten. Este truco además de [Java](http://ideone.com/oInXz) funcionará (por ejemplo) en Perl, .NET y JGSoft, pero no en [PHP](http://ideone.com/9ZVhK) (PCRE), Ruby 1.9+ o TextMate (ambos Oniguruma). La bandera adhesiva de JavaScript `/y` no es tan flexible como `\G`, y no se podría usar de esta manera incluso si JS admitiera la búsqueda hacia atrás.

Esto no funcionará en Android, que no tiene soporte para el uso de `\G` en búsquedas hacia atrás.

Basado en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761521/255257) de StackOverflow en inglés.